# Check “five in a row” for a 15x15 chess board (part 2)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

This is a follow-up from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153460/check-five-in-a-row-for-a-15x15-chess-board). I have a further optimization for space complexity by store only direction status data for one row for each directions (refer to variable `stats`). Any advice on algorithm time complexity improvement, code bugs or code style advice is highly appreciated.

> **Problem**:
>
> For a given board, judge who had complete a continuously line (could
>   be horizontal, vertical or diagonal) of 5 pieces. Input is a 15×15
>   chess board, could be white (1), black (2) or empty (0). Return if
>   white win, if black win, if both win or if none of them win.

```
import random
import pprint
def check_five(matrix):
    directions = [(0,-1),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(-1,1)] # (row, col)
    stats = [[0] * len(directions) for _ in range(len(matrix[0]))]
    WHITE = 1
    BLACK = 2
    EMPTY = 0
    WIN = 5
    BLACK_WIN = False
    WHITE_WIN = False
    # init first row
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        if matrix[0][i] != EMPTY:
            for j in range(len(directions)):
                stats[i][j] = 1
    for row in range(1, len(matrix)):
        for col in range(0, len(matrix[0])):
            for d_i, d_v in enumerate(directions):
                if matrix[row][col] == EMPTY:
                    stats[col][d_i] = 0
                elif len(matrix)>row+d_v[0] >= 0 and len(matrix[0])>col+d_v[1] >= 0 and matrix[row][col] == matrix[row+d_v[0]][col+d_v[1]]:
                    stats[col][d_i] += 1
                else:
                    stats[col][d_i] = 1
                if stats[col][d_i] == WIN:
                    if matrix[row][col] == WHITE:
                        WHITE_WIN = True
                    else:
                        BLACK_WIN = True
                    if WHITE_WIN and BLACK_WIN:
                        return (True, True)

    return (WHITE_WIN, BLACK_WIN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matrix = [[random.choice([0,1,2]) for _ in range(15)] for _ in range(15)]
    pprint.pprint(matrix, indent=4)
    print check_five(matrix)
```

Comment: You might add some targeted test cases.  For instance, this does not detect a diagonal win 1,1 to 5,5.

Answer (score 3):

What an interesting little problem!

You don't need to accumulate any stats at all, if you just test each cell for whether it is at the *centre* of a line of 5 all the same colour. This also means that, for example, you don't need to look at first two and last two columns when searching for a horizontal line, and similarly for rows and diagonals.

Here's a (rather wholesale) modification of your code. All the real work is done in the winning_cell() function, which just tests the four lines that this cell is at the centre of. This leaves the main loop in check_five() very clean.

Although there's a lot of work in winning_cell, on a randomised matrix this runs about 30% faster.

(EDIT: this is in Python 3.6 - I've just noticed you are on 2.7. Apart from the brackets round the print statement I'm not sure what else this would affect.)

```
import random
import pprint

# Offsets from the current cell to cells that might form five in a row
# with the current cell as centre, calculated here so as to be outside
# the main loop
OFFSETS = (-2,-1,+1,+2)
DIAG_1 = [*zip(OFFSETS,OFFSETS)]
DIAG_2 = [*zip(OFFSETS,reversed(OFFSETS))]

def winning_cell(m, row, col):
    """ True if the given cell is at the centre of a row of 5 """
    # Note that when checking for a horizontal line we don't need to
    # check the first two or last two columns - the same logic applies
    # to rows and diagonals.
    colour = m[row][col]
    # check within row
    if (1 < col < len(m[0]) - 2 and
        all([m[row][col + c] == colour for c in OFFSETS])):
        return True
    # check within column
    if (1 < row < len(m) - 2 and
        all([m[row+r][col] == colour for r in OFFSETS])):
        return True
    #check diagonals
    if (1 < col < len(m[0]) - 2 and
        1 < row < len(m) - 2 and
        (all([m[row + r][col + c] == colour for r, c in DIAG_1]) or
         all([m[row + r][col + c] == colour for r, c in DIAG_2]))):
        return True
    return False

def check_five(matrix):
    WHITE = 1
    BLACK = 2
    EMPTY = 0
    BLACK_WIN = False
    WHITE_WIN = False

    # main loop to check cells
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for col in range(len(matrix[0])):
            cell = matrix[row][col]
            if (cell == EMPTY or
                cell == WHITE and WHITE_WIN or
                cell == BLACK and BLACK_WIN):
                pass
            else:
                if (cell == WHITE and winning_cell(matrix, row, col)):
                    WHITE_WIN = True
                if (cell == BLACK and winning_cell(matrix, row, col)):
                    BLACK_WIN = True
                if WHITE_WIN and BLACK_WIN:
                    return (True, True)

    return (WHITE_WIN, BLACK_WIN)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    matrix = [[random.choice([0,1,2]) for _ in range(15)] for _ in range(15)]
    pprint.pprint(matrix, indent=4)
    print (check_five(matrix))
```

Comment: `DIAG_1` and `DIAG_2` would also affect the portability.

Comment: Thanks @Dex'ter. Doubtless there's another way of doing it - I'll have a look when I get back from work.